# Different ways to compute median and percentiles in Descriptive Statistics

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

I am learning Descriptive Statistics from [UC BERKELEY](https://courses.edx.org/courses/BerkeleyX/Stat2.1x/2013_Spring/courseware/36bcbc2a9dbd4f4b8546f13c035b2759/3dbc206731424bb9aaa8ada47fb8a274/) online edx course.
Median even according to wikipedia is defined as (n/2)th term if number of terms are odd and avg of (n/2)th+((n+1)/2)th if terms are even of the ordered list.But according to the lecture,it is defined as-

"The pth percentile of a list of numbers is the smallest number that is at
least as large as p% of the list."

Using this definition yields significantly different answers than the one stated above

For example-

0, 2, 4, 7, 7,12 median = 5.5(according to traditional way)

0, 2, 4, 7, 7,12 median = 4(using the above defintion)

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way for an odd number of terms is the $\frac {n+1}2$th term.  It agrees that the median is $4$, as with $5$ terms we want the $3$rd.  The two $7$s count as separate terms.  The traditional way you cite does not account for other percentile values.

Comment: sorry i have editied the question please reply according to new statement